# pygame rotatating image

Tags: image, rotation, pygame

I've been trying to make my turret rotate correctly, however, when I move my mouse (causing the rotation) the turret rotates above the tankbase, does anyone know an easy way to fix this? Help would be appreciated, please note this is my first attempt at pygame though

Code:

```
#Rotation
mousex,mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
CalcHeight = cannonBase.y - mousey
CalcWidth = cannonBase.x - mousex
if CalcWidth == 0:
   CalcWidth = 1
CalcRot = CalcHeight/float(CalcWidth)
rot = math.degrees(math.atan(CalcRot))

OldCenter = cannonBase.center
rot_image,rot_rect = rot_center(cannon_original, cannonBase, rot)
cannonBaseStretchedImage = rot_image


#Rot_center
def rot_center(image, rect, angle):
     """rotate an image while keeping its center"""
     rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
     rot_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center=rect.center)
     return rot_image,rot_rect
```

(my first time posting, please tell me if my post in anyway was hard to read or understand)

*Added pics

Thanks for the fast replys, here is 2 pics (Couldn't uploud via stackoverflow since I was to low of a grade)

http://imageshack.us/a/img266/606/prntscrnpygame.png
http://imageshack.us/a/img507/3848/prntscrnpygame2.png

Note that I'm very aware the the rotation is somewhat off, I just wanted to fix the location first, hope we can fix this!

Comment: what do you mean by rotation above the tank base?

Comment: Perhaps post a screenshot?

Comment: It would really help if you put an image of what you mean.  I have almost no idea.

Comment: Added pics, thanks for the fast respone guys!

Comment: My computer has software that is blocking it, but if you e-mail me at violin.anderson@live.com, I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the e-mail.  Your problem is that the center of rotation is off.  You have to make it so the center of the turret is the exact center of the image.  I'll e-mail you a picture of what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, this was one of the theories I thought of myself, however I was worried that it might cause weird hitbox erroors later when I try to shoot at other tanks, is there no other  way? no way to find the base of the pic? Otherwise, thanks very much, I'll see to it to have it fixed!

Comment: @TobiasLaving To avoid hitbox errors, you can just ignore the turret when doing colisions.  Instead, just use the tank's rect.  That way the turret's size won't matter.